# Usage of do_action and add_adction

Tags: actions

I'm trying to use add_action to add HTML output to a plugin's front end area,
Below is the snippet from plugin

```
<ul class="dashboard-links">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dashboard_links['commissions'] ?>"><?php _e( 'Commissions', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dashboard_links['clicks'] ?>"><?php _e( 'Clicks', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dashboard_links['payments'] ?>"><?php _e( 'Payments', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dashboard_links['generate_link'] ?>"><?php _e( 'Generate link', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dashboard_links['settings'] ?>"><?php _e( 'Settings', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>
    <?php do_action( 'yith_wcaf_after_dashboard_links', $dashboard_links ) ?>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to extend it by adding the snippet written below in functions.php

```
function add_link_to_aff() {
    $html_output =  "<li><a href='#'><?php _e( 'Test', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) ?></a></li>";
    return $html_output;  
}
add_action( 'yith_wcaf_after_dashboard_links', 'add_link_to_aff', 10 );
```

This is the snippet which I'm g, I also tried passing `$dashboard_links` to the function but it didn't worked.

Comment: Actions don't use a return value. Why aren't you printing out the HTML immediately?

Comment: Do you mean adding in in the plugin's file or doing echo inside function?

Comment: Referring to your `add_link_to_aff()` function, with the `do_action()` function, you need to `echo $html_output;` (and not `return` it). If it was `apply_filters()` as in `apply_filters( 'yith_wcaf_after_dashboard_links', $dashboard_links )`, then you'd do something like `return $dashboard_links . $html_output;` (and not `echo` the `$html_output`). So in your case, `do_action` = *do something after the default dashboard links are printed* and not filters the dashboard links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `echo` your data. Try this instead -

```
function add_link_to_aff() {
    $html_output =  "<li><a href='#'>" .  __( 'Test', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ) .  "</a></li>";
    echo $html_output;  
}
add_action( 'yith_wcaf_after_dashboard_links', 'add_link_to_aff', 10 );
```

Comment: I already tried but this didn't worked.

Comment: Just updated my answer. There was a syntax error. Try again.